# Display the text "..." in mvc view vb.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there any way that you display the "..." text in a view in vb.net MVC.  For Example I am trying to do this:

```
@If item.IssueSummary.Length > 50 Then
     @item.IssueSummary.Substring(0, Math.Min(item.IssueSummary.Length, 50)) @Html.DisplayName("...") 
Else
     @item.IssueSummary
End If
```

But the ... will not display like this (it will just be blank), Doing @Html.DisplayName("more") will work so is there anyway this can be displayed as text?

Just typing ... in the view gives and syntax error too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just escape it like so...

```
@if (true)
{
    @:...
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Putting the string expression in brackets @(anystring) should work:

```
 @("...")
```